# Create spot instances in different regions

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to create spot instances in different region using boto3.
My default regions defined as us-east-1.

When I'm trying to create the spot instances in different region from the default one , an exception is thrown with this message:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the RequestSpotInstances operation: Invalid availability zone: [eu-west-2b]
```

The instances created using this code snippet:

```
for idx in range(len(regions)):
    client.request_spot_instances(
            DryRun=False,
            SpotPrice=price_bids,
            InstanceCount=number_of_instances,
            LaunchSpecification=
            {
                'ImageId': ami_id,
                'KeyName': 'matrix',
                'SecurityGroupIds': ['sg-5f07f52c'],
                'SecurityGroups': ['MatrixSG'],
                'InstanceType': machine_type,
                'Placement':
                    {
                        'AvailabilityZone': regions[idx],
                    },
            },
    )
```

Comment: If you go into the EC2 management console in that AWS account and go to the London region, what AZs are displays when you try to launch an EC2 instance (in the Subnets field)? Also, is that Security Group defined in `eu-west-2`? (BTW, there's probably no need to include both `SecurityGroupIds` and `SecurityGroups`.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the security group exists in that region. I also copied the AMI to that region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your `regions` list actually contains a list of **Availability Zones** rather than regions (since it says `'AvailabilityZone': regions[idx]`).

Each AWS region operates independently. When making a connection to an AWS service, you must connect to the specific service **in a specific region**.

For example:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
```

This connects to EC2 in your **default region**.

Alternatively, you can specify a region:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = 'eu-west-2')
```

You are receiving the `Invalid availability zone` error because your client is connected to a region (eg `us-east-1`) but is referencing an Availability Zone that is in a different region (eg `eu-west-2b`).

Your code is only creating the client once, but is attempting to connect to multiple regions. The solution is to **create a new client connection** for the region you wish to use.  If your loop connects to multiple regions, then the `client` should be defined **within the loop** rather than outside the loop.